# alinear TextView desde java en Android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

Estoy intentando alinear un TextView desde el codigo java, eh encontrado algunos ejemplos para el padding y el margin pero para lo que quiero no, simplemente trato de hacer un android:layout_alignParentRight="true" desde java, ALGUNOS CODIGOS FUNCIONAN AL CREAR NUEVOS TEXTVIEW PERO LO QUE NECESITO ES MODIFICAR UNO QUE YA ESTA CREADO EN EL LAYOUT XML

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/RL1">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/tv1"/>
```

JAVA

```
package com.example.myapplication;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
private void alinear(){



        TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        txt.setId(1);
        txt.setText("hola**********");


        //obtener id del Layout donde esta el comtrol
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RL1);
        //definir variable para los cambios en los parametros del control
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParamas;
        //establecer la configuracion inicial del Layout
        relativeLayoutParamas = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //agregar regla de alinieacion del control
        relativeLayoutParamas.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        //enviar las reglas al control
        relativeLayout.addView(txt,relativeLayoutParamas);

       }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Tu código por ejemplo quedaria de la siguiente manera
Con gravity centrado, con LayoutParams WRAP_CONTENT que se adapta al texto si solo vas a tener un texto por linea usa MATCH_PARENT.

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        alinear();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    private void alinear(){

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.RL1);

        TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams paramsExample = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        txt.setId(1);
        txt.setText("hola**********");
        txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        txt.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        txt.setLayoutParams(paramsExample);
        relativeLayout.addView(txt,relativeLayout.getLayoutParams());

    }
```